# Хочу сделать для своего тг бота на python приветсвенную карточку как в примере

Tags: python, бот, telegram

[image: вот пример]

Хочу сделать для своего тг бота на python приветсвенную карточку как в примере.
Буду очень благодарен за любую помощь

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: вот вам в виде помощи рекомендация почитать документацию. за вас тут никто ничего делать не будет - обращайтесь к фрилансерам за деньги. а вот если нужно помочь разобраться с вашим кодом - тогда милости просим.

Answer (score 0):

Это делается через @BotFather в Telegram нажатием на кнопку "Edit Description Picture". Там уже отправляете картинку.